# How to define discontinuous boundaries in SciPy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, boundary

I'm using scipy.optimize.minimize 'SLSQP' method, according to the documentation:

> bounds : sequence, optional
>
> Bounds for variables (only for L-BFGS-B, TNC and SLSQP). (min, max) pairs for >each element in x, defining the bounds on that parameter. Use None for one of min >or max when there is no bound in that direction.

I'd like to know whether it is possible to define a boundary which is NOT continuous for a variable x like (0,15) & (30,50); (x is between 0 and 15 and between 30 and 50)

Or are there any other better methods to achieve this?

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> x is between 0 and 15 and between 30 and 50

This would make the model infeasible. There is no such `x`. You probably mean:

x is between 0 and 15 **OR** between 30 and 50

This is non-convex, so standard local solvers have troubles with this. It is often modeled with an extra binary variable:

```
30 δ ≤ x ≤ 15(1-δ) + 50 δ  
δ ∈ {0,1}
```

Of course, this assumes you can handle binary variables (SLSQP can't). Models with binary variables and nonlinear constraints (or objective function) are called MINLP models (Mixed Integer Non-linear Programming). Solvers for these type of models are readily available.

Some other approaches that may work:

- Solve the problem twice. Once with `0 ≤ x ≤ 15` and once with `30 ≤ x ≤ 50`. Then pick the best solution.
- Use the `scipy.optimize.basinhopping` global solver to help your way out of a local optimum. This is not a rigorous algorithm (no guarantees), but it can help.

Some approaches that typically don't work:

- instead of a binary variable `δ ∈ {0,1}` use a continuous variable `δ ∈ [0,1]` and add the constraint `δ(1-δ)=0`. Typically this will get you stuck.
- The polynomial approach in the other answer: this is also non-convex and not really suited for SLSQP. You will get stuck in a local optimum.
- Add a penalty to the objective if `x ∈ [15,30]`. This also does not work with a local solver.

Comment: Thanks for the comment regarding the polynomial approach. Could you elaborate on what could go wrong? Is there documentation or other resources that explains what goes wrong with non-convex constraints or (even better) a simple example which exposes the problem? (I don't understand the comment about local optimum since AFAIK (almost) all scipy minimizers find local optimums (at best)).

Comment: Ah, I see -- if you choose a guess, `x0`, in `30 < x0 < 50`, then the optimizer only finds the minimum in that interval. (So to find the minimum over the entire region, you'd have to run the minimizer twice with an appropriate guess in each interval.)

Comment: @unutbu Correct. Local solvers are very dependent on the starting point when the model contains non-convexities,  Non-convex models are not that easy,

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt at implementing the basinhopping approach [described by Erwin Kalvelagen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50353752/190597).

First, construct a polynomial with roots at 0, 15, 30, and 50
which is positive in the desired region:

```
In [123]: x = np.linspace(-1, 51, 100)

In [124]: plt.plot(x,-(x-0)*(x-15)*(x-30)*(x-50))
Out[124]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fa01d65b748>]

In [125]: plt.axhline(color='red')
Out[145]: <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fa01d6620b8>

In [146]: plt.show()
```

[image]

Now you can use that polynomial as a constraint:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize

cons = (
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -(x-0)*(x-15)*(x-30)*(x-50)}, )

def f(x):
    return (x-20)**2

res = optimize.basinhopping(f, [40], minimizer_kwargs={'method':'SLSQP', 'constraints': cons}, niter=10, stepsize=20)
print(res)
```

yields

```
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 13
     nit: 4
    njev: 4
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([15.])
                    message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
      minimization_failures: 0
                       nfev: 178
                        nit: 10
                       njev: 56
                          x: array([15.])
```

Note that the initial guess was at `40` and yet `optimize.basinhopping` managed to find the minimum in the other non-contiguous interval at `x = 15`.
Using a stepsize which is on the order of the distance between the two intervals is important to allow `basinhopping` an opportunity to sample from both intervals.

Without basinhopping, `optimize.minimize` using SLSQP with a non-convex constraint may fail to sample from all admissible intervals. For example,

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -(x-0)*(x-15)*(x-30)*(x-50)}, )

def f(x):
    return (x-20)**2

res = optimize.minimize(
    f, [40], method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
print(res.x)
# [30.]

res = optimize.minimize(
    f, [5], method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
print(res.x)
# [15.]
```

shows you would have to run `optimize.minimize` twice with a guess in each interval
in order to find the true minimum.